# Проблема с функцией в структуре

Tags: c++, структуры

У меня в структуре есть средний бал по трем предметам (mark). Он должен высчитываться в функции (average). Код не компилируется с ошибками, которые ниже. В чем может быть проблема?

Ошибки:

```
Ошибка  2   error C2676: бинарный "[": "student" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору    C:\Users\User\Documents\!OOП\ПР 4\Задание 2\Задание 2, 18 вариант.cpp   45  1   Задание 2
Ошибка  3   error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель C:\Users\User\Documents\!OOП\ПР 4\Задание 2\Задание 2, 18 вариант.cpp   46  1   Задание 2
Ошибка  4   error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель C:\Users\User\Documents\!OOП\ПР 4\Задание 2\Задание 2, 18 вариант.cpp   47  1   Задание 2
Ошибка  5   error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель C:\Users\User\Documents\!OOП\ПР 4\Задание 2\Задание 2, 18 вариант.cpp   48  1   Задание 2
Ошибка  6   error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель C:\Users\User\Documents\!OOП\ПР 4\Задание 2\Задание 2, 18 вариант.cpp   49  1   Задание 2
```

Строки:

```
        read(s[i]);
        sr_rating += s.physics[i];
        sr_rating += s.programming[i];
        sr_rating += s.math[i];
        sr_rating = s.mark[i];
        sr_rating = 0;
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct student
{       char surname[21];
        char group[21];
        int course;
        int physics;
        int programming;
        int math;
        float mark;
        // Информация о рабочих
        char WorkersName[21];
        char JobTitle[21];
}; 
void read(student & s)
{       cout << " Фамилия: ";
        cin >> s.surname;
        cout << "\n Группа: ";
        cin >> s.group;
        cout << "\n Курс: ";
        cin >> s.course;
        cout << "\n Физика: ";
        cin >> s.physics;
        cout << "\n Программирование: ";
        cin >> s.programming;
        cout << "\n Математика: ";
        cin >> s.math;
        cout << "\n Имя рабочего: ";
        cin >> s.WorkersName;
        cout << "\n Должность рабочего: ";
        cin >> s.JobTitle;
} 
void print(student & s)
{       printf("\t%10s  \t", s.surname);
        printf("\t%10s  \t", s.group);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.course);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.physics);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.programming);
        printf("\t\t%1d   \t", s.math);
        printf("\t%.2f \t", s.mark);
}
void average(student & s) {
    float sr_rating = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        read(s[i]);
        sr_rating += s.physics[i];
        sr_rating += s.programming[i];
        sr_rating += s.math[i];
        sr_rating = s.mark[i];
        sr_rating = 0;
    }
}
int main()
{   student *s;
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n = 3;
    cout << "Введите количество студентов > ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    s = new student [n];
    cout << "\nВведите данные > \n" ;
    printf("\tФамилия:\t\tГруппа:\t\tКурс:\t\tФизика:\t\tПрограммирование:\t\tМатематика:\t\tСредний:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        print(s[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так вам компилятор же ясно описывет все ошибки, в чем проблема?...

Comment: Если честно, то я не понимаю, что нужно сделать)
Я нуб)

Comment: Обьект `s` является экземпляром  ՝student՝,  вы пишете: `read(read(s[i])`;  Что такое `s[i]`, компилятору не известно, потому что в  `student`   вы не определили `operator[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в комментариях показал где есть исправления, вам остается лишь сравнивать и стараться понять:

```
void print(const student& s)
{
    printf("\t%10s  \t", s.surname);
    printf("\t%10s  \t", s.group);
    printf("\t%1d  \t", s.course);
    printf("\t%1d  \t", s.physics); // <-
    printf("\t%1d  \t", s.programming);
    printf("\t\t%1d   \t", s.math);
    printf("\t%.2f \t", s.mark);
}
void average(const student& s, const int n) { // <-
    float sr_rating = 0;
    //откуда в функции появилась n? ^нужно передать этот n 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        read(s);      // <-
        sr_rating += s.physics;
        sr_rating += s.programming; // <-
        sr_rating += s.math;      // <-
        sr_rating = s.mark;     // <-
        sr_rating = 0;
    }
}
```

И ваши функции не модифицируют данные студента, поэтому передайте по константной ссыльке(с модификатором const)

Comment: В конце программы не забывайте  освобождать память  под массив

Comment: да, я тут просто не смотрел что вы делаете, У вас и логическая ошибка: функция   average практически ничего  не делает,